# React action with data in map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Now I got code like this:

```
<select onChange={(event) => onChangeSize(event.target.getAttribute('size-id'))} className="form-control select__product">
 {
   sizes.map((size, idx) => <option size-id={size.id} key={idx}>{size.size} {size.isLast ? 'Last size!' : ''}</option>)
 }
</select>
```

it's works perfectly fine, but may be I can execute onChangeSize in other way? without using  "size-id" attribute? I don't think this is best practice

Comment: I dont think, its good practice to target element from DOM like this.

Comment: It's fine, but I'd grab `.target...` in the onChangeSize function to keep my JSX clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply give the `<Option />` tag a value and keep track of that:

```
<select onChange={(e) => setSelectedId(e.target.value)} className="form-control select__product">
      {
        sizes.map((size, idx) => <option size-id={size.id} value={size.id} key={idx}>{size.size} {size.isLast ? 'Last size!' : ''}</option>)
      }
      </select>
```

Full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-xsfck?file=/src/index.js

In general, try to stay away from mixing DOM hooks too much with logic. The React ecosystem is powerful exactly because you're not limited to working on a DOM like e.g. jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, you said that I need to stay away from mixing DOM hooks too much with logic. But in this case I can't do nothing better?

Comment: @Dimabytes in my example you separate it. The classic notion of using data-X attributes are from the paradigm of not having a declarative way of interacting with the DOM. You inject X data from the server, that is picked up by Y framework on the frontend, by reading the DOM. In React your "DOM" is a data structure (AST), and can be treated just as data. That means you have a lot more control over it. An example is that refs in react are only used in certain cases as they are a direct hook to the actual DOM. It's a longer discussion, but the simple answer is to stay away from "reading" the DOM.